# Continuity of a composition function

Tags: calculus

For functions $f$ and $g$ both continuous at $x=0$, $f(g(x))$ can be discontinuous at that particular point since if $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$ and $g(x) = x-1$ then $f(g(x)) = \frac{1}{x}$ which is obviously not continuous at $x = 0$.

Does this still hold if the domain of $f$ and $g$ is both $\mathbb{R}$? The domain of function $f$ in the example above is $\mathbb{R} - \{-1\}$, so I would like to know if there are other examples of both $f$ and $g$ being continuous at $x = a$ and $f(g(x))$ discontinuous at $x = a$, with $domf = domg = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In order to decide if $f(g(x))$ is continuous at $0$ you have to know what $f$ does at $g(0)$: you obviously don't care about what $f$ does at $0$. On the other hand, if $f$ is continuous at $g(0)$ and $g$ is continuous at $0$, then $f\circ g$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I know what you mean, I'm just trying to find an example where both functions have $\mathbb{R}$ as their domains.

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $g$ is continuous at
$b = f(a)$. then the composite function $h = g ◦ f $ is continuous at $a$

Comment: @emilagazade: True, but not what the question asks.

Comment: yes sorry I misunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Take the functions $g(x) = x + 1$ and $f(x) =\begin{cases} x, & \text{if $x$ rational} \\ a, & \text{if $x$ irrational} \end{cases}$

They are both continuous at $a$, $dom(f) = dom(g) = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(g(x))$ is discontinuos at $a$.

However, if you assume $f(x)$ to be continuous at $g(a)$ and $g(x)$ to be continuous at $a$ then $f(g(x))$ would always be continuous at $a$ since for all $\epsilon$ > 0, there must exist some $\delta$ > 0 such that $|x-g(a)|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(g(a))| < \epsilon$. Now, given that $g(x)$ is continuous at $a$, we know that for all $\epsilon´$ > 0 there exists some $\delta´$ > 0 such that $|x-a|<\delta´ \implies |g(x)-g(a)| < \epsilon´$, so let´s make $\epsilon´= \delta$, then we know that for some $\delta´$, $|x-a|<\delta´\implies |g(x)-g(a)| < \delta \implies |f(g(x)) - f(g(a))| < \epsilon$ so by the definition of continuity we can conclude that $f(g(a))$ will always be continuous.